# Snow Leopard dock - when I minimize files, where do they go?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, icons, dock

I upgraded to Snow Leopard a while ago.

Recently, when I minimize files in any application the files disappear - no icon that I can find, showing how to bring to a dominant window any of the minimized files.  I search, can't find, have to re-boot app., and lose data.  Not good.

When I minimize files, where do they go, how do I reopen them, and how can I change it so icons for all minimized files remain visible?

Answer (score 1):

They hide behind the application icon in the Dock. So, if you minimise three windows of a particular application, they will all hide behind the icon for that application in the Dock. You can click on the application icon to restore the last minimised application, or click and hold the application icon in the Dock to choose which of three minimised applications you want to restore.